# Scss dependency inside scss file using bower

Tags: sass, dependencies, bower

I'm developing a scss framework similar to bootstrap for my own projects.

This project is a registered bower package. And in my scss files I'm depending on another bower package that i need to `@import` in my other scss files.

It seems that just declaring dependency in the bower.json file is not enough.

**What is the right way to include dependent scss files from other bower packages?**

This is my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "pre-cortex",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "authors": [
    "Ole Henrik Skogstrøm"
  ],
  "description": "a scss framework",
  "main": "pre-cortex.scss",
  "keywords": [
    "pre-cortex",
    "cortex"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "compass-breakpoint": "~2.5.0"
  }
}
```

And this is my main file:

```
// This first line is not correct. This does not work when the package is installed in other projects. 
@import "bower_components/compass-breakpoint/stylesheets/breakpoint";

@import "components/css-reset";
@import "components/form-reset-helpers";
@import "components/variables";
@import "components/typografi";
@import "components/grid";
@import "components/helpers";
@import "components/nav-horizontal";
@import "components/nav-vertical";
@import "components/jumbotron";
@import "components/well";
@import "components/form";
@import "components/button";
```

Comment: compile your Sass with the `--load-path` pointing to the parent folder of bower_components

Comment: see also , see also https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#includepaths

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? I'm not sure i get what you mean. Where do i set this? and does this apply for ruby sass?

Comment: How do you compile your sass code now?

Comment: I got it working now, thank you for the hint with load path. I Looked closely at the build output and sa that it threw an error about not finding the file with any of the current loadpaths. I corrected the import path to this: `@import "../../bower_components/compass-breakpoint/stylesheets/breakpoint";` That works however it is not guarantied that other projects have a similar setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this based on @BassJobsen comment.

Use the normal @import path in the bower package that you are trying to include to your project. For example:

```
@import "../compass-breakpoint/stylesheets/breakpoint";
```

The problem was that i was using `bower link` to refer to my development version of the package (read more about `bower link` [here](http://bower.io/docs/api/#link)). Normally this is the correct path.

With bower link. This caused the path to be wrong when including with @import '../etc/etc'. since the package is just symlinked in.

To solve this just add a an additional loadpath to the compiler. I'm using gulp so for me i added this line to my styles.js file: `loadPath: ["bower_components/angular"]`

Example:

```
var sassOptions = {
  style: 'expanded',
  loadPath: ["bower_components/angular"]
};
```

the result is that one of the load paths are now:

```
bower_components/angular/../compass-breakpoint/stylesheets/breakpoint
```

Which works perfectly, both for linked bower packages and normal installed ones. :)